# Java: why does Collection.addAll can not accept Iterables?

Tags: java, iterator, iterable

I wonder why the `Collection.addAll()` method only accepts other `Collection`s but not `Iterable`s. Why is that?

Any similar method to do that for `Iterable`s?

Comment: if you are looking for the easiest way to add an iterator to a collection without an explicit loop, you could use `yourCollection.addAll(org.apache.commons.collections.IteratorUtils.toList(yourIterable.iterator()))`

Comment: and in case your Iterable is an array, use `java.util.Arrays.asList()`

Comment: Arrays do not implement `Iterable`

Comment: @SteveKuo: Can you elaborate the meaning of that with respect to the question?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Presumably because the `Collection` interface was introduced in Java 1.2 whereas `Iterable` appeared only in 1.5, and changing the interface would break all existing implementations.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the method wasn't subsequently added.

Comment: @user48956: yes, it does: "changing the interface would break all existing implementations". Though that actually became untrue with the introduction of default methods in Java 8.

Comment: @user48956: not sure why you think that is relevant. It's not.

Comment: Because it was possible to add addAll(Iterable) into addition to addAll(Collection) when Iterable was added. Was there some reason it wasn't added?

Comment: @user48956: To repeat myself a third time: "changing the interface [by adding a method to it] would break all existing implementations [because they would now be missing that method]". That's the kind of braking change that will NEVER happen in the Java Standard API.

Comment: I'm very confused. How does adding an additional method cause a method to be missing?

Comment: @user48956: I'm not sure how much more clearly I can spell it out: There are classes whose code says "implements Collection". If you add a method to the Collection interface, then those classes are now missing that method and will not compile (or, if already compiled, fail validation during class loading) when used with the new version of Java where Collection has that method. And this loss of downward compatibility (where old code won't run on a new version of Java) is something that Java jas traditionally avoided at all costs.

Comment: They could've added a `Collections.addAll(coll, it)` for `Iterable` and `Iterator` in Java 5 though, with a `@see` on `Collection#addAll`. Granted, it can't be clever about downcasting the argument, but I'm pretty sure most of the workarounds aren't doing that either.

Comment: This doesn't explain why it wasn't added as a default method in Java 8. I'm leaning towards [@OscarRyz's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3832084/1553851) that it has to do with `Collection` representing a finite set of elements.

Answer (score 35):

When in doubt, always check Guava (or Commons):

- Guava: [Iterables.addAll](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-java.lang.Iterable-)
- Commons Collections: [CollectionUtils.addAll](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-java.lang.Iterable-)

Comment: +1 for *When in doubt, always check Guava*. Most apache commons libs are great, but commons / collections is annoying because it doesn't support generics.

Comment: It has a fork which supports generics: https://github.com/megamattron/collections-generic

Comment: Broken link. Now http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/index.html

Answer (score 13):

Others have answered the "why" extensively.

> Any similar method to do that for Iterables?

In Java 8 you don't need `addAll` any more:

```
Collection<X> coll = ...;
Iterable<X> it = ...;
it.forEach(coll::add); // coll.addAll(it);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Knew it was possible with just the JDK. Thanks!

Comment: Does that work if the stream if a parallel stream? You would then call `coll.add` concurrently.

Comment: Anyone has done some benchmarking on this? Is it comparably fast?

Comment: This is not a good solution, since it makes the iterable responsible for the iteration. You give away control in how iteration is done. With an addAll method you simply request the source to provide an iterator. With the **overridable** forEach method you are not in control how the iteration is done. Therefore you can't make any estimates related to performance.

Answer (score 11):

Basically because an `Iterable` may never end (that is, [`hasNext()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#hasNext--) return true forever).

Also, to keep congruency, you may think a `Collection` may add all the elements of another collection, but, an `Iterable` is not necesarily a collection (it may be anything, like the a `ResultSet` wrapper for instance).

Comment: Ah, your first point is a good one. I don't really understand what you mean by the second one and how it would affect the `addAll` method.

Comment: As for the second, an iterable is an interface, pretty much, anything, could implement it, and you may end up in the first situation, with an possible infinite loop.

Comment: Not sure I agree. A Collection can be infinite in the same way as an Iterable, as you can construct a valid Collection as a wrapper around an Iterable.

Comment: Nevermind, I've checked the doc, http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#size%28%29  it should return Integer.MAX_VALUE

Comment: @GaryF I don't think collections are supposed to be infinite collections, or `removeAll()` and `retainAll()` could execute indefinitely. @OscarRyz just because size may be greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` doesn't mean it can be infinite. And the interface doesn't even properly support collections larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, since `toArray()` promises to return all the elements even though arrays can't be larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few things in the core JDK which don't work as well with plain Iterables as they might. I'd recommend using [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki) to overcome a lot of these shortcomings.

Comment: Hi, can you list shortly some of these shortcomings?

Comment: @ctomek: It would really be a list of what Guava makes available, which is best shown by following the link and seeing what it provides...